# What are reasons for a OpenGL program to become invalid?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently searching for a bug which is based on a OpenGL program being invalid. But it is difficult to find the source of the problem without knowing where it might come from.

When I create the program it is valid. Furthermore I don't use `glDeleteProgram()`.

To determine wether my program is valid or not I use [`glIsProgram()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glIsProgram.xhtml).

Comment: Are you printing out GLSL compile error log already? Or what do you mean by _invalid_?

Comment: @harism The GLSL compile logs are ok. Valid means glIsProgram() returns true. (Described in the documentation)

Comment: My bad. Could you elaborate a bit more on how you manage your program id/object? Do you call glDeleteProgram at any times - possibly while it's still in use? Are you recreating it if context has been lost?

Comment: Have you run tracer for OpenGL ES? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html

Comment: @harism I edited my post to make it more clear. The error occours although the context has not been lost.

Comment: @todd I didn't know there is a tool like this. Thank you very much. I am going to try it.

Comment: @todd unfortunately GLTrace gives me the error: _Error while launching application: Timed out waiting for application to launch._ I did anything described in [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html) link.

Comment: `glIsProgram (...)` does ***not*** tell you if a program is valid. That only tells you if there is a program object with that name in existence in your OpenGL context. If you never bind a program (e.g. call `glUseProgram (...)`) it is never "valid" by your definition of "valid."

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman So do I have to call glUseProgram() to get my program "valid"? And is my program "invalid" until I use it?

Comment: Names do not become objects until you call `glUseProgram (...)` once. Until that point, `glIsProgram (...)` will return ***false***. That is because all `glIsProgram (...)` tells you is if a program object has been created or not, and object creation in OpenGL happens the first time you bind an objcet.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Your comment solved my problem. Would you like to write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Generally in OpenGL, objects are not created until they are first bound.

`glGenTextures (...)` for instance, reserves and returns one or more ***names*** for texture objects but those names do not become actual textures until bound to something like `glBindTexture (GL_TEXUTRE_2D, ...)`. In other words, the names are reserved but what they reference is not instantiated/initialized yet.

What `glIs* (...)` actually returns is whether the name you pass it is the name of a created object. Thus, if you never bind an object it is never created, and this function will return `GL_FALSE`.

`glUseProgram (...)` is the function that OpenGL uses to bind GLSL program objects. Even though GLSL program and shader objects work differently from all other types of OpenGL objects it is very likely that `glIsProgram (...)` is ***not*** going to return `GL_TRUE` until sometime after you have called `glUseProgram (...)` on it at least once.

---

Incidentally, to validate a program I would suggest you use `glValidateProgram (...)` instead.

#### Here is some C pseudo-code that demonstrates how to use `glValidateProgram`:

```
GLint valid = GL_FALSE;
glValidateProgram (program);
glGetProgramiv    (program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &valid);
```

If `valid` is `GL_TRUE` after this, your program is valid (e.g. it was successfully linked).